# I'm trying to delete menuItems from an optionMenu with a seperate button, in maya python

Tags: python, maya

I'm writing this code to import textures. I pull them into a drop down menu and I'm trying to make another button that will give me the ability to remove the menuItems from that optionmenu. The clearList function at the bottom is the part that I'm having a lot of trouble with. That function probably doesn't make any sense right now because I have no idea how I'm going to accomplish this. Here's my code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os.path
import os

class TextureImport():
    def __init__(self):
        if cmds.window(TextureImport, q=True, ex=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(TextureImport)
        GUI=cmds.window(title="Texture Import Tool", widthHeight=(250,200), s=True, tlb=True)
        cmds.columnLayout(adj=True)
        cmds.button(label="Select Directory", command=self.selectDir)
        cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', label="File List")
        cmds.button(label="Clear List", command=self.clearList)
        cmds.flowLayout()
        cmds.text('Select your object!', h=25)
        cmds.button(label="Apply Texture")
        cmds.setParent('..')
        cmds.showWindow()

    def selectDir(self, *args):
        basicFilter = "Image Files (*.jpg *.jpeg *.tga *.png *.tiff *.bmp *.psd)"
        myDir = cmds.fileDialog2 (fileFilter=basicFilter, dialogStyle=2, fm=3)
        myFiles = os.listdir(myDir[0])
        print myFiles

        for items in myFiles:
            fileEndings = ('.psd','.PSD','.jpg','JPG','.jpeg','.JPEG','.tga','.TGA','.png','.PNG','.tiff','.TIFF','.bmp','.BMP')
            if items.endswith(fileEndings):
                cmds.menuItem(items)
            else:
                cmds.warning(items + 'This is not a valid image type, you fool.')

    def clearList(self, *args):
        cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True)
        if optionMenu != 0:
            deleteUI (optionsMenu, menuItem=True)
TextureImport()
```

Comment: Why are you importing `os.path` then the entire `os` module?

Comment: Not sure, I'm actually pretty brand new to coding in general. Should I only be pulling the os.path?

Comment: Well for one it doesn't seem like you're even using `os.path` anywhere, just `os.listDir`. For this instance I would just just have `from os import listDir`, that way you can just run `listDir` without `os` in front. However, if you were to use multiple functions from the `os` module than I would just put `import os` and call it a day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the menu *items*, you have to call `deleteUI` on the items:

```
def clearList(self, *args):
    menuItems = cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True, itemListLong=True) # itemListLong returns the children
    if menuItems:
        cmds.deleteUI(menuItems)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing the option menu to a variable:

```
def clearList(self, *args):
    cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True)
    if optionMenu != 0:
        deleteUI (optionsMenu, menuItem=True)
```

Should be

```
def clearList(self, *args):
    menu = cmds.optionMenu('optionMenu', q=True)  # stored result
    if menu:                                      # took out unnecessary comparison
        cmds.deleteUI(menu, menuItem=True)        # added "cmds." for consistency of namespace
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! I got that working, and it doesn't throw errors anymore, but it doesn't actually remove anything from the list whenever I use it.

Comment: Thanks @user3225017, I've posted a different answer that actually works!